# Make me some sushi

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

It's lunch time, I am hungry and I came to your Sushi Bar. You are the Sushi Chef and you have to produce a full program or function to make me some sushi!

[image] <sup>[Credits: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushi)</sup>

<sup>*Disclaimer: The image is for illustration purposes only and do not necessarily represent the exact product.*</sup>

Although you have limited ingredients (due to a truck drivers strike) it will be fine for me.

The ingredients you have (in plenty amount) are:

- Nori seaweed (made with: `\/_¯|`)
- Raw Tuna (`T`)
- Raw Salmon (`S`)
- Raw Avocado (`A`)
- Sushi Rice (`o`)

With these ingredients you are able to make some nice makis for your clients.

Your minimum order is $1 for 2 makis, you only make makis in couples and only accept integer numbers as payment. You accept orders up to $50 per person (total input) because you are alone and you must satisfy all your clients.

You will need to get the client's orders from standard input in any reasonable format, for example: `[1,T],[2,S],[3,A]` which means that you have to output:

- Two Tuna Makis
- Four Salmon Makis
- Six Avocado Makis

One maki is exactly made like this:

```
   _____  
  /ooooo\ 
 |ooTTToo|
 |\ooooo/|
 | ¯¯¯¯¯ |
  \_____/
```

And since you are a fine Sushi Chef, you always arrange the makis with the pieces of any given type in a square shape or at most in a rectangular shape (as close as possible to a square) with no gaps. The overall shape is also square or rectangular, as close as possible to a square given the above restriction, with no gaps.

**Example input/outputs:**

```
Input: [1,T],[2,S],[3,A]

Valid Output:
  _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooTTToo||ooTTToo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 

Valid Output:
  _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooTTToo||ooTTToo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/   

Not Valid Output:
  _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooTTToo||ooAAAoo||ooSSSoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooSSSoo||ooAAAoo||ooTTToo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 

Not Valid Output:
  _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\
|ooTTToo||ooTTToo||ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 


Not Valid Output:
  _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\
|ooTTToo||ooTTToo||ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 


Input: [1,S]

Valid Output:
  _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/ 

Valid Output:
  _____  
 /ooooo\ 
|ooSSSoo|
|\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/ 
  _____  
 /ooooo\ 
|ooSSSoo|
|\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/ 


Input: [1,A],[1,T],[1,S]

Valid Output:
  _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooAAAoo||ooTTToo||ooSSSoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooAAAoo||ooTTToo||ooSSSoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 

Valid Output:
  _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooTTToo||ooTTToo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 

Input: [1,T],[1,A],[2,S]

Valid Output:
  _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooTTToo||ooTTToo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 

Valid Output:
  _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooTTToo||ooTTToo||ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/     

Valid Output:
  _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooTTToo||ooTTToo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/   


Input: [1,T],[1,S],[7,A]

Valid Output:
  _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooTTToo||ooTTToo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/    

 Valid Output:
  _____    _____     
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\    
|ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|   
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|   
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |   
 \_____/  \_____/    
  _____    _____     
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\    
|ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|   
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|   
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |   
 \_____/  \_____/    
  _____    _____     
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\    
|ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|   
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|   
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |   
 \_____/  \_____/    
  _____    _____     
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\    
|ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|   
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|   
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |   
 \_____/  \_____/    
  _____    _____     
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\    
|ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|   
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|   
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |   
 \_____/  \_____/    
  _____    _____     
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\    
|ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|   
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|   
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |   
 \_____/  \_____/    
  _____    _____     
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\    
|ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|   
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|   
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |   
 \_____/  \_____/        
  _____    _____     
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\    
|ooSSSoo||ooSSSoo|   
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|   
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |   
 \_____/  \_____/    
  _____    _____       
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  
|ooTTToo||ooTTToo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/
```

**Rules:**

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

Comment: "You are the Sushi Man": I believe that assuming the reader is male is a manifestation of unconscious gender bias, that contributes to women and nonbinary people feeling unwelcome in tech contexts.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks for your comment. You are right. I changed the title and the text to avoid any gender specification.

Comment: Awesome, I like the changes!

Comment: In the first test case `[1,T],[2,S],[3,A]`, is it valid or invalid to arrange them so that the top row is TTSA, the scond row is SSSA, and the bottom row is AAAA? It's not clear whether this satisfies "all the similar types close to each other"; they are certainly touching.

Comment: @GregMartin no it is not valid as you proposed, you must arrange each individual group into squares or rectangles, in your case the S and A are not. It could be SSSS, TAAA, TAAA for example.

Comment: What would we do then for the input `[1,T],[1,S],[7,A]`?

Comment: @GregMartin for the input `[1,T],[1,S],[7,A]` the output would be for example: first row `TSAAAAAAA`, second row `TSAAAAAAA`. I added this test case in the examples.

Comment: Ah ok: what do you think of this wording? "you always arrange the makis with the pieces of any given type in a square shape or at most in a rectangular shape (as close as possible to a square) with no gaps. The overall shape is also square or rectangular, as close as possible to a square given the above restriction, with no gaps."

Comment: @GregMartin I think it is clear, you have to group the same type in square or rectangle and the whole order in square or rectangle shape. In your last example `[1,T],[1,S],[7,A]` you can make a a 2x7, or 7x2, rectangle with 1x2 of T, 1x2 of S, 7x2 of A. Same as 2x1 T, 2x1 S, 2x7 A.

Comment: The ambiguity which I think my wording clears up is that the individual types of sushi have to be "as close as possible to a square", and this is more important than that the overall rectangle be "as close as possible to a square" if the two are in conflict. In the case `[1,T],[1,S],[7,A]`, for example, you want the whole rectangle to be 2x9 rather than 3x6, because 2x9 is the only way to make all individual sushi types into rectangles.

Comment: @GregMartin Ah ok I see now... I thought you were asking clarification on that rather than suggesting an improvement. I will apply that suggested edit. Thanks for your help and contributions, my english is not the best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Python 3, <s>314</s> 313 bytes

```
l=["  _____  "," /ooooo\ ","|oo%s%s%soo|","|\ooooo/|","| ¯¯¯¯¯ |"," \_____/ "];T=('T',)*3;S=('S',)*3;A=('A',)*3;i=eval('['+input()+']');x=sum(map(lambda x:x[0],i));m=[]
for f in i:m+=[f[1]]*f[0]
for p in 1,0:
    for j in l:
        for k in range(x):print((j%m[k]if '%s' in j else j),end='')
        print()
```

My attempt at this challenge. It's hard!

#### Sample Output:

```
[1,T],[1,S],[7,A]
  _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooTTToo||ooSSSoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/ 
  _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____    _____  
 /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\  /ooooo\ 
|ooTTToo||ooSSSoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo||ooAAAoo|
|\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/||\ooooo/|
| ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ || ¯¯¯¯¯ |
 \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/  \_____/
```

Comment: Instead of using tabs you could use spaces for level one indentation and tabs for level two indentation.  This will save you 2 bytes overall.

Comment: The space in `'%s' in` is also unnecessary.

Comment: you don't need the space after `if`. Python2 would save you one indentation and also the prints ad input. maps are longer than comprehensions if you have to use lambdas.